# How to create an array so that it display all users data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I couldn't loop through score record. It keeps replacing the score of new user but does not display the record of previous user.

Here is the code. 
users.php

```php
public function show_per($matricnum)
{
    $query=$this->conn->query("select * from percentage where matricnum='$matricnum'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($query->num_rows>0)
    {
        $this->data[]=$row;
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

viewre.php

```html
<div class="container">
  <center><h2>Student Result Record</h2>   
  <?php 
     $i=1;
    foreach($result->data as $view)
    {?>  
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Matric Number</th>
        <th>Result</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $view['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $view['matricnum'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $view['per'];?></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php $i++; }?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thank you sir for the info. Really helpful for me. @tadman

Comment: Thank your sir @Dmitry for editing my sentences. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public function show_per($matricnum)
{
    $query=$this->conn->query("select * from percentage where matricnum='$matricnum'");

    if($query->num_rows>0)
    {
        while ($row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            $this->data[]=$row;
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

You call `fetch_array()` method which returns only one row. You need a loop to go through all rows, then when it takes all rows it will return `NULL` and the `while` loop will stop.

And BTW, you can use `fetch_assoc()` instead `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

Comment: Nice answer! Just wondering.. is the num_rows check necessary if you initiate the $this->data as an array? Since while($row = NULL) will stop the loop?

Comment: @GerritLuimstra You're right, it's not necessary. I kept it to remain original code as much as possible